# a question about transpose and inverse of matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, transpose

I have a question about transpose and inverse of matrix.

> Let $\boldsymbol X$ and $\boldsymbol Y$ be any matrices.
>
> Please calculate this expression step by step: $$\left[\left(\boldsymbol{X}^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol{Y}\right)^{-1}\right]^\mathsf{T}$$ where ${}^\mathsf{T}$ is transpose.

Answer:

$$\left[\left(\boldsymbol X^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol Y\right)^{-1}\right]^\mathsf{T}=\left[\left(\boldsymbol X^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol Y\right)^\mathsf{T}\right]^{-1}=\left[\boldsymbol Y^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol X\right]^{-1}=\boldsymbol X^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol Y$$

Is this right?

Comment: You also have to assume $X,Y$ are invertible.

Comment: I've suggested edits, but for your future reference: (a) when the material you're parenthesizing is tall, use `\left(` and `\right)`, `\left[` and `\right]`, etc.; (b) for matrices, the “best” notation is slanted bold, as in `\boldsymbol{X}`; (c) the transpose looks cleanest and clearest if you format it `^\mathsf{T}`. You can find more in the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll use that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$ and $(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
((X^T Y)^{-1})^T
& = (Y^{-1}(X^T)^{-1})^T \\
& = (Y^{-1}(X^{-1})^T)^T \\
& = ((X^{-1})^T)^T(Y^{-1})^T \\
& = X^{-1} (Y^T)^{-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Why $(Y^TX)^{-1} = X^TY$? It should be $(Y^TX)^{-1} = X^{-1}(Y^T)^{-1}$.